# How can I refer to another pgf key using a pgf style argument?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

Trying to explain what I am trying to do is harder than just demonstrating it, so here is a simplified version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  application node/.style={rectangle, draw=red},%
  node/.style n args={1}{#1, append after command={\pgfextra{\let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode}
  node [above] at (\mainnode.north) {#1}
}}}

\begin{document}
\tikz \node [node={application node}] {host.domain.com};
\end{document}
```

The following should happen:

- `node={application node}` refers to PGF key `node` which takes 1 argument, which is defined as *application node*
- TikZ/PGF expands the argument *application node* in `node/.style` as `node/.style n args={1}{application node, ... \node [above] ... {application node}`
- `application node` is parsed as a PGF key, being adding `rectangle, draw=red` in its stay

I refer to the PGF key `application node` as `#1` in the `node` key.

The problem is how `#1` is tokenized. The PGF key parser sees `a` and looks for a key called `a` instead of `application node`.

Comment: I don't know what you want from your code. Can you provide a hand-writing draft?

Comment: Just use `node/.style={...}` instead of `node/.style n args={1}{...}`

Comment: If you insist on using `node/.style n args={1}{...}` you need to double the braces, i.e. `\node [node={{application node}}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, TikZ requires an argument pattern when the PGF parser is supposed to read all of the tokens stored in `#1` (until the closing brace).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  application node/.style={rectangle, draw=red},%
  node/.style args={#1}{
    #1,  
    append after command={\pgfextra{\let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode}
        node [above] at (\mainnode.north) {#1} 
      },%  
    },%  
}

\begin{document}
\tikz \node [node={application node}] {host.domain.com};
\end{document}
```

Henri Menke pointed out that I could have also double braced the argument `{{application node}}` and kept the `.style n args` syntax.

Relevant Excerpt from the TikZ/PGF Handbook

> Because of the special way the *value* is parsed, if you set
> *value* to, for instance, |first| (without any braces), then |#1| will
> be set to |f| and |#2| will be set to |irst|.

Comment: `pgfkeys` strips the braces around arguments if there is only a single pair.  This has to do with how TeX reads arguments. Pretty sure that is mentioned somewhere.

Comment: Yes, it is mentioned: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/54af91f0b247a2d147db67ef58e2271814a68d29/doc/generic/pgf/text-en/pgfmanual-en-pgfkeys.tex#L1022-L1024

Comment: In general, in TeX if you have a problem where part of your argument is chopped off, try adding extra braces.

Comment: In fact, if you had used `/.style` rather than `/.style n args` you would have had no such problem, because `/.style` can proactively work around this, since it will only take a maximum of one argument.

Comment: I should probably mention the brace stripping a bit more prominently.  Right now you sort of have to read between the lines and know that the `/.style` handlers are implemented in terms of `/.code` handlers.

Comment: I've opened a new issue for that: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/912